# Callback when GameObject is serialized

Tags: serialization, unity-game-engine

Is there any callback (or any other way) to be notified before a `Unity3D` serializes a `GameObject`?

I need something similar to [OnSerializeNetworkView](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnSerializeNetworkView.html) but for a regular `GameObject`.

Useful scenarios:

- Store non-serializable fields into serializable classes
- Several possible optimizations on class fields

Any idea?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful downvote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the question time it wasn't possible. By `Unity 4.5` version a class implementing [ISerializationCallbackReceiver](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html) interface will be notified before been serialized and deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this function](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AssetModificationProcessor.OnWillSaveAssets.html).

If you implement a custom AssetModificationProcessor, you should be able to preprocess your custom GameObject.